# What is the output of this aggregator

Tags: informatica

Quick question, here is my data
Data_field:  100|address|place|456|687

This column from expression is being passed to aggregator and marked as group by in aggregator.

What will be the output of this aggregator? also can u tell me something brief about aggregator?

Thanks,
Teja

Answer (score 0):

Firstly say for example your data is consisting of 3 records

Data                        amount

100|address|place|456|687   10

100|address|place|456|687   20

100|address|place|456|687   30

In informatica if its  group on Data and SUM(amount), the output will be

100|address|place|456|687   60

Say for example if there is no amount column as below

100|address|place|456|687

100|address|place|456|687

100|address|place|456|687

In informatica if its  group on Data then your output is as below

100|address|place|456|687 only one record

In the above scenario One important note about aggregator is , even though
you have not checked the groupby option , informatica by default selects the last record

Aggregator in informatica is similar to using aggregate functions like '**MAX**', '**MIN**', '**COUNT**' etc., upon group in SQL

example : Say if you want to know the max salary in a department then

SQL

select dept, count(*) from employee group by dept;

Informatica

you can enable the groupby option on dept and then create a port which will have max(salary). this will give the output similar to the SQL above

Things to take care in aggregator for better performance:
1) Use Sorter transformation before aggregator

2) Use number columns in group by whenever possible (try to avoid date and string columns)

3) If the source is having huge number of records its better to group the records in SQL override itself because the aggregator will create cache.

4)Add filter if required to avoid unnecessary aggregation

Hope this helps

Regards

Raj

Comment: Hi Raj, Thank u so much for explaining so clearly. My data is coming this way 100|address|place|456|687  and then 101|address|place|909|687 and then 102|address|place|897|000 so group by on this column what will be the output of this?   Also can u let me know if we are checking group by columns for two fields? There exists only two columns and group by is checked on both the columns what does it do?

Comment: The output will be 

100|address|place|456|687
 
101|address|place|909|687  

102|address|place|897|000

Assuming the entire record is a single column

Since entire data is different for the three records , informatica considers this as 3 groups and 3 records will be moved to the output/target

Refer to aggregator in transformation guide for more information

Comment: So is it necessary to be passed into aggregator, it can be passed into expression also right? If its simply passing the records?

Comment: Hi Teja,
it completely depends on your requirement. if your requirement says that you need to group the similar records and do some aggregation then you need to use aggregator. otherwise if you want all the records coming from source to target , then single expression will do the job

Comment: Thank you very much Rajendra. I got you :) Really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Aggregator transformation can be used for multiple aggregation operation such as AVG, COUNT, FIRST, LAST, MAX, MEDIAN, MIN, PERCENTILE, STDDEV, SUM and VARIENCE . GroupBy option can be checked to calculate the aggregates of a column as  per your condition..

For example,

consider the source,

[image]

Aggregaion function is provided as,

[image]

Average of HEIGHT and maximum of WEIGHT is calculated by grouping POSITION column. Target is obtained as,

[image]

As POSITION column is grouped, Average of HEIGHT and maximum of WEIGHT is populated for each value avaliable in the POSITION column.

Aggregation transformation is nearly as same as SQL aggregation functions and SQL groupby clause.

Comment: Thanks Jim for clear explanation, I got about it. Well explained!!

Comment: You are welcome buddy. In case of any doubts regarding informatica transformations let me know